# Issue while showing result of a query from database to DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

working with an assignment here i am able to view all data from database to grid view but the data appears to be `unsorted` and it displays all data i only want to `display the result of a query` in the `DataGridView` the code i have tried is :

```
private void btnmeritbsit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbpath);
    string query = "select Applicant_no,A_Name,Father_Name,T_Matric,O_Matric,M_Percentage,T_Inter ,O_Inter ,I_Percentage from applicantinfo order by I_Percentage desc";
    con.Open();
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = sdr.FieldCount;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sdr["Applicant_no"], sdr["A_Name"], sdr["Father_Name"], sdr["T_Matric"], sdr["O_Matric"], sdr["M_Percentage"], sdr["T_Inter"], sdr["O_Inter"], sdr["I_Percentage"]);
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

i was getting the whole values through `datatable` and `dataAdapter` but nothing works !!stuck!!

```
// DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
// sda.Fill(dtbl);
// dataGridView1.DataSource = dtbl;
```

Comment: _i was getting the whole values through datatable and dataAdapter_ which would be the normal way. when changing to datareader (why?) you need a little more code. which you have, but all in the wrong order. Look again: Why ExecuteReader before the conection is opend, why close right after and why add rows outside of the loop? You can also combine datatable with reader.Load to achieve databinding.

Comment: The root cause of your issue is that your query lacks a WHERE clause. Adding a dataset to your project, configuring a tableadapter inside it with a parameterized where clause and then dragging the representation of the grid out of the data sources window and onto your form would solve everything in 0 lines of c# code and one SQL, written by you. I don't have enough time to write this up as an answer at the moment but you could take a look at the bulleted list in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543864/filling-two-different-datagridview-with-different-tables-from-same-db/62544068#62544068

Comment: @CaiusJard can you explain it a bit more

Comment: @TaW would you let me know about that by adding few edits in my code?

Comment: Move the con.Open one line up and the con.close after the loop and the rows.add into the loop. report back about the result..!

Comment: Move the con.Open one line up and the con.close after the loop and the rows.add into the loop. report back about the result..!  More changes: You need to add the columns yourself, maybe like so: `dataGridView1.ColumnCount = sdr.FieldCount;` or one by one . You also need to access the data maybe like so: ` dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sdr["Applicant_no"], sdr["A_Name"], .....);`

Comment: @TaW if there's nothing in textboxes it should show the database values but

Comment: Have you read the link I gave?

Comment: @CaiusJard i tried to understand that the best way as posible but no0thing helped much :p

Comment: Before adding new rows call `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();` method.

Comment: When using the DataTable, do this `dataGridView1.DataSource = null; dataGridView1.DataSource = dtbl;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works perfectly fine just after a few changes :)

```
private void btnmeritbscs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            string dbpath = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-UMA0VFO;Initial Catalog=ApplicationForm;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbpath);
            string query = "select prgstatus,Applicant_no,A_Name,Father_Name,T_Matric,O_Matric,M_Percentage,T_Inter ,O_Inter ,I_Percentage from applicantinfo where prgstatus like 'bscs' order by I_Percentage desc";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);  
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = sdr.FieldCount;


            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sdr["prgstatus"], sdr["Applicant_no"], sdr["A_Name"], sdr["Father_Name"], sdr["T_Matric"], sdr["O_Matric"], sdr["M_Percentage"], sdr["T_Inter"], sdr["O_Inter"], sdr["I_Percentage"]);
            }
            con.Close();


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What I wrote in the other answer, in pictures. This is using a VB app, but it doesn't matter because the steps are the same and you're not actually going to be writing much more than one line of code

[image]

Right click project, add new dataset

[image]

Right click surface, add tableadapter

[image]

Add a connection string, Next. Name it, Next

[image]

Add a query that selects all from your table, WHERE (id column) = @id

[image]

Rename the methods to add "ByID". It will be obvious why later. Finish:

[image]

Right click table adapter, Add Query

[image]

Proceed through choosing "Select that returns rows" and entering a query that seeks users by last name:

[image]

Give good names to the new methods. Finish. Save:

[image]

Go to the forms designer, make sure Data Sources tool panel is showing (View Menu)

[image]

Drag the Users grid node from Data Sources onto the form

[image]

It has pre-made a textbox for the ID, because that's the first query in the tableadapter. We'll change it to lastname. Click the button, change its name, change the text it shows. Always make sure your control names are up to date and relevant.

[image]

You can see I changed the label too, and I also changed the name of the textbox (you can't see it) and I changed the name of everything in the tray under the designer, so it starts with underscore:

[image]

I do this because VB is case insensitive and calling variable the same name as their type is a bad idea in any language, and makes intellisense confusing in VB. You don't have to add the leading underscores in C#. It's enough to discriminate on case alone, though arguably not always wise:

[image]

Now we need to change the code. Double click the FillBy button. It goes to code. Maybe you have some code already, maybe not. Make sure the code fills the table using the relevant input. This is the only part of the process that really requires you to think about what you're doing and what your variables are called (they may be different to mine)

[image]

The code probably defaulted to saying

```
_usersTableAdapter.FillByID(_myDataSet.Users, new Guid(_lastNameToolStripTextBox.Text));
```

Because it used to be set up for you to type an id (guid or int, my db has a guid) in that box but we have changed it for lastname. So we need to change the FillByID (and now you see why we give them sensible names, not FillBy1 and FillBy2) so it's FillByLastName, and we need to change the code so we pass a string lastname, not a guid ID

```
_usersTableAdapter.FillByLastName(_myDataSet.Users, _lastNameToolStripTextBox.Text);
```

That's the only code you have to write. **Remember** I named my things on the form using leading underscores, so my code has leading underscores. If you dont rename your things, your code won't have leading underscores

Now run the app:

[image]

Look at all those John Smiths! They are different users, of course - the ID is different for every one. You can even write new details in here and press save to update the db..

From one line of code! :)